# Disabling Webcam by blacklisting driver - what are the consequences?

Tags: drivers, security, webcam

I am a new Ubuntu user, and for security reasons I would like to disable my webcam unless I need it.

The most appealing solution to do so seems to blacklist the webcam driver, as outlined [here](https://thelinuxcode.com/disable-microphone-webcam-ubuntu/).

Before I proceed with this, however, I have two questions:

- When needing the webcam, is it enough to simply remove the driver from the blacklist.conf file, or does it need to be re-installed?
- Does the system need to reboot in order for changes in the blacklist.conf file to take effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install/uninstall **kernel modules** (we don't call them 'drivers') anytime using the modprobe command.

The blacklist merely lists modules to not install at boot. YOU are not governed by the blacklist - after boot you can change anything anytime. For a webcam, a restart should not be necessary.

See `man modprobe` for how to install/remove/list modules.

- To disable hardware by default, blacklist the module.
- To enable the hardware temporarily, install the module...and then uninstall the module when complete.

Of course, you can also just put a piece of opaque tape over the webcam, too.